# Clickable items in listview - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I created a ListView in my app and each item of the list corresponds to some place. I want to become the items clickable to, when the user clicks on the name of the place, a map location appears. How can I do that? How can I make the items of the list clickable and that go to different links?

This is my Activity:

```
public class Guia extends BaseActivity {

     String[] predios={"HVET - Hospital Veterinário", "FE - Faculdade de Educação", "BSA SUL - Bloco de Salas de Aula Sul", "BAES - Bloco de Salas de Aula Eudoro de Sousa",
     "FACE - Faculdade de Administração, Contabilidade e Economia", "FD - Faculdade de Direito", "PAT - Pavilhão Anísio Teixeira",
     "PJC - Pavilhão João Calmon", "IPOL/IREL - Instituto de Ciências Políticas/Relações Internacionais", "CIC/EST - Prédio de Ciência da Computação e Estatística",
     "RU - Restaurante Universitário", "IDA - Instituto de Artes", "ICC - Instituto Central de Ciência",
     "CDT - Centro de Tecnologia", "CPD - Centro de Informática", "FM/FS - Faculdade de Medicina/Saúde", "CEU - Casa do Estudante", "Centro Olímpico"};

    ListView s;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.guia);

        s = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.predios);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.predios, R.id.textosiglas, predios);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

and this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EBEBEB"
    >

    <ListView
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/predios"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:divider="#EBEBEB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my xml adapter:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagemguia"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/guia"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textosiglas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Also refer documentation... `setOnItemClick` is shown there too. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luiz's answer is correct. But you do not especially need to implement the fonction. You can make a new instance instead :

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
@Override
Public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View p2, int i, long p4)
    {
    // Your stuff here
    }
});
```

Where p1 is your listView, p2 is the clicked view (useful for finding text and changing it inside), p3 is the position in the listView, p4 the unique id.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `Interface` named `OnItemClickListener`, so change your `Activity` to implements the interface:

```
    public class Guia extends BaseActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

         String[] predios={"HVET - Hospital Veterinário", "FE - Faculdade de Educação", "BSA SUL - Bloco de Salas de Aula Sul", "BAES - Bloco de Salas de Aula Eudoro de Sousa",
         "FACE - Faculdade de Administração, Contabilidade e Economia", "FD - Faculdade de Direito", "PAT - Pavilhão Anísio Teixeira",
         "PJC - Pavilhão João Calmon", "IPOL/IREL - Instituto de Ciências Políticas/Relações Internacionais", "CIC/EST - Prédio de Ciência da Computação e Estatística",
         "RU - Restaurante Universitário", "IDA - Instituto de Artes", "ICC - Instituto Central de Ciência",
         "CDT - Centro de Tecnologia", "CPD - Centro de Informática", "FM/FS - Faculdade de Medicina/Saúde", "CEU - Casa do Estudante", "Centro Olímpico"};

        ListView s;


        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.guia);

            s = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.predios);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.predios, R.id.textosiglas, predios);
            s.setAdapter(adapter);

           //This is class that implements the interface.
           s.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }

       //This method is implemented using the interface
       @Override
       public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id){
      //Trate o click de cada item aqui dentro usando a variavel position

       }
}
```